# Explanation of >> operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I have edited a piece of code that is designed to read integers from a .txt file and display them using cout. It is designed to display the first integer followed by a comma then the running total average the problem was when there was blank lines or singke integers in the .txt. i was advised to change the code to :

```
  using namespace std;
  # include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include<string>

int main ()
{
double y = 0,x = 0,value1 =0;
string myFileName,myString;
cout<< "please enter the name of the file you wish to open"<<"\n";
cin>>myFileName;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(myFileName.c_str());

while (!inFile.eof())
{
    double currentAv;

    //while(getline(inFile,myString,(' ')))
    while(inFile>>value1)
    {


        y=y+1;
        //value1 = atof(myString.c_str());
        currentAv=(value1+x)/y;
        cout<<value1<<","<<currentAv<<endl;
        x=value1+x;
    }

}





inFile.close();
system("pause");
}
```

the 2 lines with // were taken out and the while loop was changed to :

```
while(inFile>>value1)
```

the problem is I need to understand what the new code does differently to the old code. can anyone help please? I know it shifts bits but I don't understand why that would work. The code does work .

Comment: It is not a bit shift, it is the [istream operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

Comment: It is reading from your `ifstream` (which is why you opened a file into it a couple lines above), then reading from that stream into your `value1` variable.

Comment: I don't really understand im a c++ noob :(

Comment: You should really look at reading an [introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This should be covered very early on.

Comment: I don't understand why the loop works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what is happening step by step.

```
inFile>>value1
```

This invokes [istream::operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), which reads a `double` from the stream and returns a reference to the stream object, that is `inFile` itself.

```
while(inFile>>value1)
```

The condition of the `while` statement must be convertible to `bool`. Now we know that type of `inFile>>value1` is `std::istream&`, and indeed, there exists [`istream::operator bool`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/), which returns `true` if no error flags are set (which would mean that the last read operation was unsuccessful).

So, the overall meaning of `while(inFile>>value1)` is: read `value1` from `inFile` while you can do it.

And about the difference compared to `getline` plus `atof`. First, `>>` reads until any whitespace character, not only space like in your code. Second, it will fail on invalid input. Third, it's just more idiomatic.